# [Vue warn]: Error in directive intersect unbind hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'observer' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I can't figure out why is this message showing. It appears only when I click on a button and I'm redirected by `router.push` to the page.

[Vue warn]: Error in directive intersect unbind hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'observer' of undefined"[image]

As I'm not sure where the problem is so I'll show you the router and also the structure:

Btw. `Streamers` is a different page, not this one (check routes below).

Can you help me?

**STRUCTURE**

App.Vue -> Dashboard.Vue -> StreamerDetail.Vue

**App.Vue**

```
<template>
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </v-app>
</template>
<script>

export default {
  data: () => ({}),
  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch('loadInitial')
  }
}
</script>
```

**Dashboard.Vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-app-bar app absolute>

    </v-app-bar>

    <v-navigation-drawer bottom color="primary" dark app>
      <v-list nav>
        <v-list-item @click="$router.push({name:'Home'}).catch(err => {})">
          Home
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-content>
      <router-view></router-view>
      <v-snackbar
          :timeout="3000"
          :value="!!$store.state.snackbar.message"
          :multi-line="true"
          :color="$store.state.snackbar.color"
          @input="$store.commit('resetSnackbar')">
        {{ $store.state.snackbar.message }}
      </v-snackbar>
    </v-content>
  </div>
</template>
```

**StreamerDetail.Vue**

```
<template>
  <v-row v-if="streamer" class="my-12">
   // even if I delete everything inside this row, the error is still present
  </v-row>
</template>
```

**ROUTER**

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Dashboard,
    redirect: '/streamers',
    children:[
      {
        path: 'streamers/',
        name: 'Streamers',
        component:Streamers,
      },
      {
        path: 'streamers/:id/detail/',
        name: 'StreamerDetail',
        component:StreamerDetail,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'Login',
    component: Login,
  }
]
```

Comment: just got a similar problem to this

Comment: Me too, have you figured it out?

Answer (score 0):

fix: update to vuetify 2.6.0

your issues is with the v-img tag, to confirm try commenting all the `v-img` inside your `v-simple-table` or in that view.

[image: issues is with the v-img tag]

It is mentioned in this issue and resolved in the latest update.

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/14390